# Is a warm breaker normal?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I have 2 15 Amp breakers both of them with a load of about 12Amps and they are warm. Is this normal that such a load should warm up the breaker?

Comment: In addition to what @speedy said in the current single answer, I would also separate those two breakers in the panel, possibly (depending on other factors) make sure the are on opposite phases, and most importantly make sure they are on a full size breaker and not half a tandem breaker.

Comment: Warm under full load is normal. Too hot to touch is not normal.

Comment: They are on separate phases

Comment: 12 amps at 120 volts is 1400 watts moving through that thing; circuit breakers are not superconductors; there's some resistance, which will turn into heat. How hot would you say the breaker is compared to, say, a 40 W incandescent light bulb?

Comment: @eric that's not how it works, the breakers have a low resistance and only drops a few volts. When calculating, you should only measure the voltage over the device, and not the total volts

Comment: @ferrybig Right. I am attempting to quantify the amount of heat observed. Warm is vague.

Comment: @eric not even. maybe 60 w flourecent

Comment: Good; that is consistent with ferrybig's observation that the resistance should be *low* in a well-functioning breaker, and also consistent with my observation that *low resistance implies non-zero resistance*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A warm breaker can be normal, yes. Especially under a heavy load.

If you are running a continuous load (80% circuit max for several hours) then I would certainly check the connections to be sure that extra heat is not causing problems. A heavy load will find a poor connection or termination and point it out to you as a problem in short order.

Comment: Does it mean that poor connections are adding to the heavyness of the already heavy load?

Comment: @aofkj, no, not adding, but can create very hot situations due to the high resistance of a poor connection.

Comment: Is 80% continuous to heavy?

Comment: 80% is the limit of a circuit for a continuous load. A continuous load is one that is *expected* to continue at full load for three hours or more. So, a 15A circuit can carry 12A indefinitely, but it should not be *expected* to carry over 12A for more than 3 hours.

Comment: Does 'point out' mean that the connections are getting warm?

Comment: No, I mean a heavy load will make a poor connection more obvious by exposing the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40856/discussion-between-aofkj-and-speedy-petey).

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. How should these poor connections be exposed to me? Isn't it by getting warm as the breaker did?